# Capturar Coordenadas Neste script Api Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

Neste scrupt a baixo eu insiro a origem e o destino ele me retorna o km o tempo e dados do endereço entre eles.
mais minha pergunta é como fazer que ele me retorne a latitude e longitude

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function CalculaDistancia() {
    $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
    // Instancia o DistanceMatrixService.
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    // Executa o DistanceMatrixService.
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()], // Origem
        destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()], // Destino
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING, // Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC // Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
    }, callback); // Vai chamar o callback
  }

  // Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
  function callback(response, status) {
    // Verificar o status.
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) { // Se o status não for "OK".
        $("#litResultado").html(status);
    } else { // Se o status for "OK".
        $("#litResultado").html("&nbsp;"); // Remove o "aguarde".

        // Popula os campos.
        $("#txtOrigemResultado").val(response.originAddresses);
        $("#txtDestinoResultado").val(response.destinationAddresses);
        $("#txtDistancia").val(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text); // se text Km se value em Metros

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var tempo = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
        tempo = tempo.replace("day", "dia").replace("hour", "hora").replace("min", "min");
        $("#txtTempo").val(tempo);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




        var dist = (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value); //pego a distancia em metros
        var km = Math.round(dist / 1000); //converto para Km e arredondo



        }}
```

Comment: Você quer a latitude e longitude do que exatamente? Porque o que essa API faz é receber latitude e longitude de origem e destino e retornar somente os dados da "viagem", como distância, tempo estimado, etc. Nesse [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=pt-br) você pode ver tudo que é trazido no retorno da requisição.

Comment: Ola...Renato. então ele retorna a distancia , tempo,etc... mais preciso receber também as  coordenadas da Origem e do Destino